# Windows 8 metro style HTML5 development

Tags: windows, html

I want to know can i develop metro style windows 8 HTML5 application without windows8 OS installed ?
I understand working on VS2012 , but Since it is web application i think it doesn't make sense to have the windows 8 OS installed.
Please confirm if it is required, if not tell me how to make it work on windows7 and VS 2012

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2012 requirements doc says that you can use it on Windows 7 SP1. However, you will not be able to develop/debug HTML5 apps developed with it as Windows 8 HTML5 applications are not simple web applications, they run on top of the WinRT runtime which is not available on Windows 7.
So bottom line, to develop/debug HTML5 applications for Windows 8, you need to have VS2012 installed on a Windows 8 machine.
If you are thinking about developing regular HTML5 web application (that will be used from a browser and not as a Windows 8 application, then you should be able to do so using Windows 7 SP1 as the host.

Answer (score 1):

See lets know more about your application.

In W8 Metro Style Apps with HTML5/JavaScript and CSS3 , you can make great apps as you can take an example of Cut The Rope .

Making a website with HTML 5 /JS/CSS3 doesnt need you to select the Windows Store App option as it is only used to create an app that would you later upload to windows store whereas a website would be uploaded on a server